# where can I find all the available properties for google material Line chart and google visualization LineChart?

Tags: google-visualization, hide, linechart

I am listening for 'select' on a Google Material Line chart legend and can determine which series was selected. How can I hide that selected series? Material Line does not support lineWidth so it can't be set to 0. Is there another property I can set for that series?

In Google visualization LineChart I am able to hide a series (lineWidth:0), but I have 4 vertical axes and the 3 secondary axes overwrite one another. Is there a way to shift the secondary axes so they do not overwrite?

Comment: maybe try setting the line color to transparent? as for the axis, try increasing `chartArea.right` -- [this page](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) lists which options material charts do not support

Comment: thx - tried 'transparent' in material chart but it was not accepted (Charts puts up a small message box when an option is not allowed). lineWidth:0 works for visualization, but the axes are buggered up if >2 axis are needed. I'll try the chartArea.right.

Comment: This URL https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechartholds the available options for the visualization LineChart. I don't see any way to adjust the position of the multiple secondary axes, and no option to set lineWidth in the Material Line. Amazing - these question postings are from 2016 - how could it take 6 years and still not have this basic lineWidth property for a line chart?